# DOMCrawler: how to select all links in "a" tag and in "area" tag

Tags: php, domcrawler

I'd like to get a list of all the links present on a page.
Some of those links are in an `area` tag.

So I do this to get a full list of all links:

```
// Get the a links
$links = $crawler->filter('a')->links();

// Append the links in area tag (clicakble images)
$links = array_merge($links, $crawler->filter('area')->links());
```

**Is there a way to select directly in the `filter` method all the links that are both in `a` tag and in `area` tag so I haven't to use the `array_merge` function?**